# Lightroom catalog on external hard drive not readable

Tags: adobe-lightroom

Using Lightroom 4, when opening a catalog file on an external hard drive, I get error

> Lightroom cannot launch with this catalog. It is either on a network volume or on a volume on which Lightroom cannot save changes.

As is suggested on the [Adobe forums](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/895028), the external hard drive is NTFS which is not compatible with my MacBook Pro.

Is there anything I could install on my computer so that the catalog is usable?

Comment: Have you tried just copying the catalog to a local harddrive?

Comment: Is there a Mac equivalent of subst? That is how to get it to work on Windows and even Linux! (My Lightroom catalog is on a Linux machine the network path is given a drive letter by subst).

Answer (score 2):

You could download a NTFS driver to read the catalog.

Saw this [driver](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/26288/ntfs-for-mac-os-x) on a first search.

If you want an alternative is to have a friend who has a windows box copy the contents out and then copy it to a drive with the correct format that you can read. I would believe this to be FAT32.

Comment: Mac and win share more than fat32, it's another FAT version whose name eludes me at the moment and which is not natively accessible from linux (maybe vfat is the name....)

Comment: vfat - for long file names in 8.3 format FAT :D

Comment: I meant **exFAT** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT